# Propositional Logic. How to determine Res^n (F)?

Tags: logic

I'm studying for my propositional logic exam and I came across this. I do not understand what this means. I know what a resolvent of two clauses are, I just don't know what I have to do. I do not want the answer to the exercise. I just want to understand what this means so I can be able to answer it on my own. If you can also give me an example problem or any other resources on this topic that will be extremely helpful. Thank you for your help!

[image: Res(f) problem]

Comment: Do you know what is the *resolvent* of two cluases ? e.g. of $\{ \lnot A, C \}$ and $\{ \lnot C \}$ ?

Comment: Thus $Res(F)$ is the set of clauses obtained adding to the "initial" set $F$ all possible resolvents obtained from couples of clauses of $F$.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Yes the resolvent will [¬A].

Comment: Correct. Then write $F$ plus all the resolvents...

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA So, I am supposed to get all resolvents of F and then add them as clauses to F? So if my F is {{¬A,C},{¬C}} then my Res(f) will be {{¬A,C},{¬C},[¬A]}?

Comment: Oh. So, my Res^0(f) = F, my Res^1 (f) = F + one resolvent, my Res^2(f) = F + two resolvents......., right?

Comment: No; $Res(F)$ is F plus **all** the resolvents of clauses of F. Call it F'; then build $Res(F')$ and this is $Res^2(F)$, and so on.

Comment: So you're saying, Res^0(F) = F, Res^1(F) = F + all resolvents, Res^2(F) = what we got from Res^1(F) + its resolvents.... Is that what you're saying? Also, do we stop whenever we cannot get any more resolvents?

Comment: Sweet, thank you so much for all your help! It finally makes sense now....